# Is possible use fade transition on tag 'content' only with css?

Tags: css, css-transitions, fade

Please view this code jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/6wCp6/

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link #3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link #4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 16px;
}
a{
    color: #000000;
}
a:hover{
    color: #860000;    
}
#menu{
    margin: 15px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #DDDDDD;

    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
}
#menu ul{
    list-style: none;
}
#menu li:before{
    margin-right: 10px;
    content: url("http://st.deviantart.net/emoticons/s/smile.gif");

    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    /* transition: content 0.5s ease 0s; */
}
#menu li:hover:before{
    content: url("http://st.deviantart.net/emoticons/r/razz.gif");
}
```

I have one image on tag 'li' and other image on 'li:hover', is possible make transition with fade only using css?

Comment: You **can't** use `animation` but you **can** use `transition`, with `opacity` or whatever to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using both pseudo elements `:before/after` and using the CSS3 transition to animate the opacity of both on hover. This will create a fade transition between both images.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/6wCp6/1/)**

CSS :

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 16px;
}
a{
    color: #000000;
}
a:hover{
    color: #860000;    
}
#menu{
    margin: 15px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #DDDDDD;

    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
}
#menu ul{
    list-style: none;
}
#menu ul li{
    position:relative;
}
#menu li:before{
    margin-right: 10px;
    content: url("http://st.deviantart.net/emoticons/s/smile.gif");

    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
#menu li:after{
    content: url("http://st.deviantart.net/emoticons/r/razz.gif");
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;

    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
#menu li:hover:after{
    opacity:1;
}
#menu li:hover:before{
    opacity:0;
}
```

---

**EDIT :**

Even better, you can position both images one on top of the other and with z-index and css transition animate the opacity of ony one image :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/6wCp6/2/)**

Comment: Very nice solution! but if I have two lines like this: [jsfiddle.net/rflfn/342CN/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/342CN/1/)? The first image disappear or appear on wrong location... You have any suggestion?

Comment: Ops... only add top:0 [jsfiddle.net/rflfn/342CN/2](http://jsfiddle.net/rflfn/342CN/2/), thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 4):

### Your case in particular

Not sure why're you trying to put images in content,

you could simply add that image as a `background-image` to the `:before`,

set it size & `display: inline-block;` and you would just animate the `background-image` like so: http://jsfiddle.net/7f695m1q/ , since background-image transition ***is*** supported :)

## TL;DR: Can `content` CSS property be animated? No.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

**OUTDATED w3.org official document:** https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/WD-css-transitions-1-20171130/#animatable-css

This may however change in future because this list is missing in current official sources:

missing in working draft https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/

missing in editor's draft https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/

So in theory there is a possibility this list will be updated and changes made in future browser versions, but currently it doesn't work.

## Is `content` affected by other animations? Yes.

Content not being animatable in itself doesn't mean it's not affected by other animations like opacity, visibility etc. It can be leveraged in at least 2 simple ways:

a) [answer by @web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23939749/1835470) provides a smooth&always visible fade effect, however, you have to sacrifce **both** `:after` and `:before` to it

b) if fadeOut => fadeIn is an option for you you can levarage CSS animations & `@keyframes`

```css
@keyframes changeContent {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    content: "See? I've changed seemlessly!";
  }
}
div:before{
  content: "HOVER OVER ME!";
  background: green;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
div:hover:before{
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation: changeContent 3s linear forwards;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div />
```

Important here is to put the "forward" - it's an animation fill mode that basically says "stop the animation at it's end", otherwise it'd jump back.

There is also one drawback - it's not easily animatable on hover-out - if I find some reasonable way I will edit this answer or please comment if you know.

Answer (score 1):

I think @web-tiki 's answer suits your needs and it's simpler. But just to show another possible solution:

You can separate the icons in two elements, each with its own content. Then, apply the transition on the `li:hover` event, setting the element's opacity inverted. Like this example:

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/2J7b9/1/

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="img1"></div>
        <div class="img2"></div>
        test
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

li .img1, li .img2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

li .img1 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

li .img2 {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

li .img1:before {
    content: url("http://st.deviantart.net/emoticons/s/smile.gif");;
}

li .img2:before {
    content: url("http://st.deviantart.net/emoticons/r/razz.gif");
}

li:hover .img1 {
    opacity: 0;
}

li:hover .img2 {
    opacity: 1;
}
```