# How to add transition in a CSS element?

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

So basically I added a picture over an element when I hovered over it, that works, but then I add:

transition: 0.2s;

And it doesn't transition, why is this? I want it to ease into the picture not just show up instantly.

Help would be appreciated.

If it's any help, I used content: url("image location"); to add the image.

Comment: Try `transition: all 0.2s;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is possible use fade transition on tag 'content' only with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938088/is-possible-use-fade-transition-on-tag-content-only-with-css)

Comment: You need to add that transition stuff on the nonhover css rules. Furthermore, you cannot simply transition an element that wasn't even there before. You also cannot transition the display property.

Comment: Did you check my answer? Asking questions on SO and not providing feedback to given answers is not how SO works.

Comment: Sorry @connexo, I haven't been active since then. My apologies. I ended up scrapping that project too.

Comment: So have you re-checked the given answers now?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you need, this will be similar:

```css
.picturehover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}
.picturehover:after {
  background: transparent url(https://lorempixel.com/300/200) center center / cover no-repeat;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out; 
}
.picturehover:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="picturehover">Some text</div>
```

Comment: i suggest you don't use `z-index:1` and `z-index:-1` because if you use it the fadeout transition doesn't work

Comment: I had added the `z-index` lines later and not checked thoroughly. Thanks for the hint, I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

i make like this

```css
.box{
  background:#333;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  transition:0.2s linear;
}
.box:hover{
  background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```